# Java - Regex replace leading zeros, but not all and keep minus

Tags: java, regex, numbers

I'm looking for a regex to replace a String to the following (number) format:

Input examples:

```
00000
00440
  235
+3484
-0004
  -00
   +0
```

Results needed:

```
    0
  440
  235
 3484
   -4
    0
    0
```

I tried to modify the following... just to leave at least + and - and remove the zeros, but I just running in circles. Can some help me?

```
input.replaceAll("^(\\+?|-?)0+(?!)", "");
```

PS: It's optional, that the +0/-0 is shown as 0, but would be a plus.

Comment: what do you plan on doing with the code, seems like you could use `Ìnteger.parseInt()` in most if not all cases

Comment: you are absolutely right. I was so into this, I haven's seen it. Thx! Instead I have to use a `BigInteger`, because i could be longer than a `long`. and i just have to remove the + before I put the string into the `BigInteger`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("^(?:(-)|\\+)?0*(?!$)", "$1");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nkseyq/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
^       # line start
(?:     # start non-capturing group
   (-)  # match - and group it in captured group #1
   |    # OR
   \\+  # match literal +
)?      # end of optional group
0*      # match 0 or more zeroes
(?!$)   # negative lookahead to assert we are not at end of line
```

---

Alternatively, you can use slightly better performing regex:

```
String repl = input.replaceAll("^(?:0+|[+]0*|(-)0*)(?!$)", "$1");
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/nkseyq/2)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
length = input.length();
for(int i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    if(input.charAt(0) == '0' || input.charAt(0) == '+' ) {
        if(input.length() == 1) {
            continue;
        }
        input = input.substring(i+1);
        length -= 1;
        i -= 1;
    }
}
```

after it `input` will be without 0's and +, but 0 will still remain as 0.